# Prevent the radio button being checked using jquery without using onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent the radio button checked when `Pinterest==1 && value=="video"` in my below code.I found the code to prevent the radio being button checked, but that code is work on click event of the button. I want to prevent the radio button
 being checked without onclick event.

```
if(Pinterest==1 && value=="video"){
    alert("You can not upload the video in Pinterest.");
    /* $('#video_type_radio').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }); */
    //Here I want to prevent the radio button being checked
}

//Radio button code
<input name="group5" type="radio" id="video_type_radio" class="with-gap radio-col-black" value="video" onchange="checkPost()" >
<label for="video_type_radio" style="margin-left:30px;">Post With Single Video</label>
```

Comment: Please provide a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So basically you want to prevent the radio button from being checked without using onclick event?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough

Comment: Off topic: @SBylemans for future ref, you can use `[mcve]` to generate link to [mcve].

Comment: ye i want to prevent the radio button from being checked without using onclick event @Code_ninja

Answer (score 1):

You can do following..

```
if(Pinterest==1 && value=="video"){
  alert("You can not upload the video in Pinterest.");
  //Here I want to prevent the radio button being checked
  $("#video_type_radio").attr('disabled', true);
 }
else{
  $("#video_type_radio").attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly disable the radio button using

```
if(Pinterest==1 && value=="video"){
alert("You can not upload the video in Pinterest.");
$("#video_type_radio").attr('disabled', true);
}
else
{  
$("#video_type_radio").attr('disabled', false);
}
```

This will disable radio button from being checked.